# My dataframe titles are not appearing properly in Python Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I am trying to create a dataframe in Google Colab in this manner because I plan to do analysis on about 1000 files later. I am having problems with the header of my variable names not registering properly. I have linked my code output as well as the expected headings.

**my output:-**

[image]

**My code is as follows:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import csv
import sys
import os
import io

# Load the Drive helper and mount
from google.colab import drive
 
# This will prompt for authorization.
drive.mount('/content/drive')

iter_changes = "Prediction"
 
PATH_TO_DRIVE_ML_DATA = "/content/drive/My Drive/Root_Work_Sample/inputs"
 
INPUT_PATH = PATH_TO_DRIVE_ML_DATA+"/work_sample"
OUTPUT_PATH = PATH_TO_DRIVE_ML_DATA+"/outputs/"+iter_changes
 
# check if directory already exists
if not os.path.exists(OUTPUT_PATH):
    os.makedirs(OUTPUT_PATH)
    print("Directory created", OUTPUT_PATH)
else:
    pass
    #raise Exception("Directory already exists. Don't override.")


df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, 'Root_Work_Sample_Stadardized_Test.csv'), engine='python')
#df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['Root_Work_Sample_Stadardized_Test.csv']))
print(df.shape)
print(df.columns)
display(df.head(5))
print(df.dtypes)
```

**My Ouput vs proper heading:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening since I don't have access to your data, but one way to solve this is to hardcode the column names:

```
header = ["your", "column", "names"]
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(INPUT_PATH, 'Root_Work_Sample_Stadardized_Test.csv'), 
                 engine='python',
                 names = header)
```

Comment: My data is going through so this will work for now. Thank you!